# Iterating through a text file with Python and storing a group of lines in separate arrays

Tags: python, text, iteration

I have a text file like this-------

```
important unimportant
important unimportant
important unimportant
unimportant
unimportant
important unimportant
important unimportant   
important unimportant
unimportant
unimportant
important unimportant
important unimportant
important unimportant
```

In this text file, I only want to extract the "important" parts and store the three lines in a row with "important" in one array separated by commas. I would then like to have create an array with the arrays mentioned before.

I am not very familiar with Python and packages related to text extraction.

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I would really appreciate help with this.

Comment: To clarify, You want to have an array with triplets of "important"s? Also, do you want to include the whole line, or just the word "important"?

Comment: How are you determining important vs unimportant?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed what your final list should look like with this input.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU try using:

```
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    l = []
    c = 0
    s = []
    for line in f.readlines() + ['']:
        if 'important ' in line:
            c += 1
            s.append('important')
        else:
            l.append(', '.join(s))
            c = 0
            s.clear()
    print(list(filter(None, l)))
```

Output:

```
['important, important, important', 'important, important, important', 'important, important, important']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sharing a lot, but what's clear is:

- you can tell an important line from an unimportant one somehow;
- you're looking to read every line of a file
- you want consecutive 'important' results to be grouped together

Loop over a file:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with `line`
```

You can collect lines that are important in a list and whenever you reach an unimportant line, or the end of the file, if there are lines in that list, add it to your result.

Putting everything together:

```
def is_important(line):
    return 'important' in line.split()  # replace with an actual test


result = []
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    important = []
    for line in f:
        if is_important(line):
            important.append(line)
        elif important:
            result.append(important)
            important = []
# done reading, add remaining important lines to result
if important:
    result.append(important)

print(result)
```

This code works for your example, just change `is_important` to actually make sense.

Note that the example code will include the newline character at the end of each line - there's various ways to get rid of it, depending on whether you want to read the whole file at once, or one line at a time. Shouldn't be hard to figure that out yourself.

If you were looking for one of those short, but hard to read solutions:

```
from itertools import groupby


def is_important(line):
    return 'important' in line.split()  # replace with an actual test


result = [list(x) for c, x in groupby(open('myfile.txt', 'r').readlines(), lambda x: is_important(x)) if c]

print(result)
```